# Server receives null when sending complex type from android client to wcf service

Tags: android, wcf, ksoap2

I am using ksoap2 library for connecting to a wcf web service. When I try to send primitive types, server gets these values and send a correct response. However, if I try to send a complex type ( an object that is a subtype of KVMSerilizable ) the server receives null. 
Below is the class definition of the object that I want to send.

```
import java.util.Hashtable;

import org.ksoap2.serialization.KvmSerializable;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;

public class TwoIntegerWrapper implements KvmSerializable {

    private int Num1;
    private int Num2;

    public TwoIntegerWrapper() {
        super();
    }

    TwoIntegerWrapper(int number1, int number2) {
        super();
        this.Num1 = number1;
        this.Num2 = number2;
    }

    public int getNumber1() {
        return Num1;
    }

    public void setNumber1(int number1) {
        this.Num1 = number1;
    }

    public int getNumber2() {
        return Num2;
    }

    public void setNumber2(int number2) {
        this.Num2 = number2;
    }

    public Object getProperty(int propertyNumber) {

        Object property = null;

        switch (propertyNumber) {
        case 0:
            property = this.Num1;
            break;

        case 1:
            property = this.Num2;
            break;

        }

        return property;
    }

    public int getPropertyCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    public void getPropertyInfo(int propertyNumber, Hashtable arg1,
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo) {

        switch (propertyNumber) {
        case 0:
            propertyInfo.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
            propertyInfo.name = "Num1";
            break;
        case 1:
            propertyInfo.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
            propertyInfo.name = "Num2";
            break;
        }

    }

    public void setProperty(int propertyNumber, Object data) {
        switch (propertyNumber) {

        case 0:
            this.Num1 = Integer.parseInt(data.toString());
            break;
        case 1:
            this.Num2 = Integer.parseInt(data.toString());
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

And here is how I call web service.

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

PropertyInfo property = new PropertyInfo();
TwoIntegerWrapper tiw = new TwoIntegerWrapper(num1Value, num2Value);

property.setName("TwoIntegerWrapper");
property.setType(tiw.getClass());
property.setValue(tiw);

request.addProperty(property);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, tiw.getClass().getSimpleName(), TwoIntegerWrapper.class);

HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

try {
    androidHttpTransport.call(Add_SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

    Log.d(logtag + " request dump", androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
    Log.d(logtag + " response dump", androidHttpTransport.responseDump);


   SoapPrimitive sp = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
   result = Integer.parseInt(sp.toString());
}
```

What are the possible reasons?

Comment: post some of your wsdl and wt error is being returned if any

Comment: The server receives a null object. My request dump is the following <v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><v:Header /><v:Body><AddNumbers2 xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" id="o0" c:root="1"><TwoIntegerWrapper i:type="n0:TwoIntegerWrapper" xmlns:n0="http://tempuri.org/"><Num1 i:type="d:int">1</Num1><Num2 i:type="d:int">3</Num2></TwoIntegerWrapper></AddNumbers2></v:Body></v:Envelope>

Comment: i will need to see your wsdl,not requestDump only, at least the message part of "TwoIntegerWrapper" , to see if you have any mistake in your code definition above

Comment: Here is the web service wsdl. http://www.ceng.metu.edu.tr/~e1559897/TestService.svc.xml

Comment: ok, now there is the "xsd" parts i can't access them coz its localhost, "http://localhost/MyService/TestService.svc?xsd=xsd0"  "http://localhost/MyService/TestService.svc?xsd=xsd1" "http://localhost/MyService/TestService.svc?xsd=xsd2" can you open each and paste them

Comment: I put those again in the link http://www.ceng.metu.edu.tr/~e1559897/

Comment: i posted an answer, check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by changing **getPropertyInfo** function of **TwoIntegerWrapper** class. I also set namespaces for each property in this class. The new implementation is the following:

```
public void getPropertyInfo(int propertyNumber, Hashtable arg1,
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo) {

    switch (propertyNumber) {
    case 0:
        propertyInfo.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
        propertyInfo.name = "Num1";
        propertyInfo.setNamespace(TWO_INTEGER_WRAPPER_NAMESPACE);
        break;
    case 1:
        propertyInfo.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
        propertyInfo.name = "Num2";
        propertyInfo.setNamespace(TWO_INTEGER_WRAPPER_NAMESPACE);
        break;
    }

}
```

Even if I remove mapping from the envelope, it works. I could not understand why it is so, but it works. I appreciate if someone explains the reason. Wsdl file, xsd0, xsd1 and xsd2 files are in the link http://www.ceng.metu.edu.tr/~e1559897/

By the way, I also changed

```
property.setName("TwoIntegerWrapper");
```

to

```
property.setName("obj");
```

Comment: Can you please let me know, what is value of "TWO_INTEGER_WRAPPER_NAMESPACE". I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 1):

One common issue for this is that, assuming you are sending XML on the wire, that the XML is in the wrong namespace. In that case the WCF deserializer will decide there is nothing that it knows about in the XML and return `null`

Comment: Namespace is correct. If not, would sending primitive types work? (cause it works with the primitive types.)

Comment: Do you control the service? If so you can turn on message logging and tracing to see what is happening on the service side

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to inspect the request and respone using [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

Enable [Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) on your WCF Service and see what is the message that comes up on the channel by inspecting the trace files.

Answer (score 0):

ok your class which implements kvmserializable is accurate based on **xsd2**.
However  the methods (**message**) that you have for **AddNumbers2,AddNumbers3** have first AN ELEMENT which HAS an element type complex type, for example:

```
 <xs:element name="AddNumbers2">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="obj" nillable="true" type="q1:TwoIntegerWrapper"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

So what you should do is :

```
property.setName("AddNumbers2");//not TwoIntegerWrapper, coz the main property is AddNumbers2
property.setType(tiw.getClass());
property.setValue(tiw);
request.addProperty(property);
```

Comment: I tried, but this did not happen to be a problem. Problem was [DataContract] and [DataMember] annotations were not written in the service codes. (so the server could not deserialize what i had been sending). When this problem was fixed, the code worked with asmx service by changind property.setName("TwoIntegerWrapper") to property.setName("obj"). But the problem continues with the wcf service. This time, however, it does not receive null, it always receives (0,0) instead.